# Operator precedence Confusion

Tags: c++, c, pointers, operator-precedence

Hello guys after going through href=http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence this link  ,
I thought I understood the operator precedence but I came to followings doubt. 
The link says that **When parsing an expression, an operator which is listed on some row will be bound tighter (as if by parentheses) to its arguments than any operator that is listed on a row further below it. For example, the expression *p++ is parsed as *(p++), and not as (*p)++.**
So how does the expression ++*p gets evaluated is it like ++(*p) but if yes ++ has higher priority or bound then *, Then why does * is bound tighter in the above case, and what about the expression *++p  ?

Comment: For `++*p`, how would you place the parentheses any other way? `++` must necessarily apply to `*p` and not `p`, because it's physically placed to the left of `*p` and not `p`. When you write `1 + 2*3`, you don't expect 1 and 2 multiplied, even though `*` binds tighter than `+`.

Comment: Answering your second question, `*++p` is equivalent to `*(++p)`. Here, too, there is no ambiguity that would require an appeal to operator precedence to resolve.

Comment: `*++p` has to be interpreted as `*(++p)` because `(*++)p` doesn't make sense--the operand of `*` has to be a value, not an operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Operator precedence defines which operator should be applied first **when there is more than one choice**.

From your link:

> Precedence and associativity are independent from [order of evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order).

The expression `++*p`, or *any* expression of the form:

```
{operator 2} {operator 1} {expression}
```

has a well-defined [order of evaluation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), where `{operator 1} {expression}` **must** be applied in order to make an expression that `{operator 2}` may act on.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `++` has higher precedence over `*` and the associativity for both is from right to left.

So

`++*p` will be evaluated as `++(*p)` because `++` need to be applied on a modifiable value.

Whereas

`*++p` as you see when this is evaluated the operator close to `p` is `++` as well as have higher precedence over `*` so `++p` will happen first followed by dereferencing `*(++p)`